# Code-Level Tracing in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, master-pages, trace

How do I define the Trace Constant for a Web Site in VB.NET to enable trace output?  I know where it is for web applications, but I cannot find it for web sites.

Comment: My bad! Have deleted my (silly) answer. :P

Comment: I appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Web Site is web application. You can enable it in web.config:

```
<system.web>
 <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true"/>
</system.web>
```